# Differential equations and axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, axiom-of-choice

In the most general context, the Picard-Lindelöf theorem (aka Cauchy-Lipschitz in French) asserts the existence of a maximal solution for $\dot{x}(t) = f(t,x(t))$, i.e. of a solution $x(t)$ defined on a interval $I$ such that there exist no other solution whose restriction  to $I$ coincide with $x$. The usual proofs of this (when $f$ is such that there is no local unicity) use Zorn's lemma, or some other weaker form of choice. But is this result actually not provable in ZF?

Comment: I though the ODE theorem for when $f$ is such that there is no local unicity, was the $\hspace{.5 in}$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem (in English).

Comment: The Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem in french or in any other language is dealing with the case where $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous with respect to $x$, i.e. satisfies an estimate of type
$$
\vert f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)\vert\le \alpha(t) \vert x_1-x_2\vert,
$$
with $\alpha \in L^1_{loc}$. In that case, local uniqueness occurs for the ODE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least for scalar equations $\dot x(t)=f(t,x(t))$, that is with a nonlinearity $f\in C^0(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$, defined on an open set  $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the Zorn's lemma is not necessary: the order structure of $\mathbb{R}$ allows to select a preferred solution (actually, two)

Any IVP  admits  an upper and a lower solution, whose domains are maximal intervals. For  $(t_0,x_0)\in\Omega$, define, for $t\in\mathbb{R}$
$$x ^ * (t):=\sup\big\{x(t)\, : x\in C^1(\mathrm{co}(t_0,t),\, \mathbb{R}),\, \mathrm{graph}(x)\subset\Omega, x(t_0)=x_0, \dot x(s)=f(s,x(s))  \big\}\, ,$$
(where of course $\sup\emptyset=-\infty$). Define
$\mathrm{dom}(x ^  *)$ to be the connected component of $t_0$ in the set $\{ t: x ^ *(t) \in\mathbb{R} \}$. Then, $x ^ *$ is a solution of the ODE with IVC $x(t_0)=x_0$, maximally defined on the interval $\mathrm{dom}(x ^  *)$.

Comment: As to the case of systems, that is $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in C^0(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$, it seems to me that the same construction can be used, using the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{R}^n$. 

Comment: A similar proof can be found in the paper of Wolfgang Walter American
Math Monthly vol 78 1971 pages 170-173 .

Comment: Actually, one should go and see the original proof of the theorem, by Giuseppe Peano. No surprise if we found it's the best proof.